# Keep only row with lowest value for each ID

Tags: excel, vba

For each ID find the value in column C and delete other rows.

I want solution only because I want to buildup on this code to add more criteria.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

I have tried coding but I am not able to get it working where it does it for each ID. It is only keeping 1 row for entire sheet.

```
Sub Celltest()
    For Each rw In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C").Rows
        For Each cel In rw.Cells
            For Each char In cel.Characters
                If char.Font.Underline = True Then MsgBox char
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: sort by value ascending then use `Range.RemoveDuplicates`

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicates. I want to keep the ID with lowest value and delete rest.

Comment: Remove Duplicates will do that if you sort it ascending first. Remove duplicates keeps the first record and removes all other dups.  If it is sorted ascending on the Value the first will be the lowest value and the others will be removed.

Comment: Thank you it does work but I kind of simplified the question so people can understand but in real data my column is from `A:K` where `A is ID` and `K is value`

Comment: I still do not see why it will not work.  You would use the full range of data and sort on K then removeduplicates based on column:=1.

Comment: Thank you so much @ScottCraner you really helped me learn something. I have 1 more  criteria . where I have two `value` columns but I think I'll try to work on it as much as I can...if I need hope I can get your help on it.

Comment: with two columns in then you would use `Columns:= Array(1,4)` where the `1,4` are the relative column numbers that contain your items that denote dups. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250875/discussion-between-user206168-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterUniqueLowestValue()

    Dim RG As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    ' Replace Sheet4 with your own Sheet CodeName
    lRow = Sheet4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RG = Sheet4.Range("A1:C" & lRow)
    
    With RG
        .Sort _
            Key1:=.Columns(3), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes
        .RemoveDuplicates _
            Columns:=1, _
            Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image] [image]

<-- **OR** -->

**With Formulas:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You may not have noticed that your VBA solution shows the wrong results. It is because you have referenced the data range (without headers) yet you are using `xlYes` as the header parameters. A simple fix would be either instead of `"A2:C"`, use `"A1:C"` or replace both occurrences of `xlYes` with `xlNo`. Also, those rows belong to a worksheet: `Sheet3.Rows.Count`. Since `rg` is referenced with the *With* statement, instead of `rg(3)` you could use `.Columns(3)`. I find it safer (I know the documentation states a single cell is Ok e.g. `.Cells(1, 3)` or `.Range("C1")` or whatnot).

Comment: can you please help me with the new question? it is slightly modified. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75021470/keep-only-row-with-lowest-value-for-two-column-for-each-id)

Comment: @VBasic2008. Both great suggestions. I changed the `("A2...` to a `("A1...` and changed the `RG` to `.Columns()`. I wasn't aware that would work as I though the key had to be a single cell.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to by formula and vba, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac). It should be pretty easy to add more criteria.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table33"]}[Content],

//Set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Value", type number}}),

//Group by ID and Name
//Then extract the minimum value for each subgroup
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Name"}, {
        {"Value", each List.Min([Value]), type nullable number}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Source***
[image]

***Results***
[image]