# Keep only row with lowest value for two column for each ID

Tags: excel, vba

For each ID find the lowest value in column C and D and delete other rows.

I want solution only because I want to build-up on this code to add more criteria.

**Criteria is:**

Each ID find the lowest `value1` and keep that entire row
also for each ID find lowest `value2` and keep that entire row.

if both lowest value for value1 and value2 are in the same row then delete other rows.

[image]

I have tried modifying the code below but it only works for 1 column duplicate.

One solution I was thinking is to highlight entire row with lowest value for each ID for Value1 and Value2
then delete the unhighlighted rows.

```
Sub test()
ActiveSheet.Range("A:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 4), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: I kept both fred because for `value2` it is `0.7` and kept second row because `value1` it is `0.4`.

Comment: I just updated the image and shown a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Okay So I *HAVE* found a solution... but it might be more complicated than doing it manually. That depends on your data size and how frequently you need to do this.

**0)** Remove Full Line Duplicates:
Filter for All
[image]

**1)** Sum your Value 1 and value 2:
[image]

Then,  **Sort** by V1 + V2, then re-sort by ID number.
This will make sure we only return 1, of there are two single minimums.
(Example at end of answer)

**2)** Check if Value 1 and Value 2 are the lowest value for ID number:
`=C2=MIN(FILTER($C$2:$C$24,$A$2:$A$24=A2))`
`=D2=MIN(FILTER($D$2:$D$24,$A$2:$A$24=A2))`
[image]
[image]

**3)** Ran `AND()` operation to see if both are min.
[image]

**4)** Run `OR()` operation to see if either are min.
`=IF(SUM(FILTER($H$2:$H$24,$A$2:$A$24=A2))>0,0,IF(SUM(FILTER($I$1:I1,$A$2:A2=A2))<2,IF(OR(F2:G2),1,0),0))`
[image]

**5)** Finally, filter list for items that have either `AND` or and `OR` :
`=FILTER(A2:D24,(H2:H24=1)+(I2:I24=1))`
[image]

---

To note, if you do not sort, it may pull the wrong ones.
This is sorted:
[image]
This is unsorted:
[image]

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% how reliable this is as I've only tested with a couple data sets.

Comment: I can imagine there being some cercumstances where this type of sorting might still lead to returning two similar answers where one isn't correct.

Comment: I considered just creating two lists, one for the Min Value 1 and one for the Min Value 2, then combining and removing duplicates... but you might miss cases where the same line in Min for both

Comment: thank you so much. I think it is working, I am testing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Again, this is something that can also be solved in Power Query.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table33"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Value1", type number}}),

//Group by ID and Name
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Name"}, {
        {"Values", (t)=>  
            let
                #"Min V1 Rows" = List.PositionOf(t[Value1], List.Min(t[Value1]), Occurrence.All),
                #"Min V2 Rows" = List.PositionOf(t[Value2], List.Min(t[Value2]), Occurrence.All),

/*If Rows are the same for both Min Value1 and Min Value2, then #"Same Row" will be non null
     so we can just return a single row
  If Intersect List is null, then we need to return separate table rows for Value1 and Value2*/
                #"Same Row" = List.Intersect({#"Min V1 Rows", #"Min V2 Rows"})            
            in 
                if List.Count(#"Same Row") > 0
                    then Table.FromRecords({t{#"Same Row"{0}}}, {"Value1","Value2"})
                else Table.FromRecords({t{#"Min V1 Rows"{0}}, t{#"Min V2 Rows"{0}}}, {"Value1","Value2"})
                ,type table[Value1=number, Value2=number]}}),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Values", {"Value1", "Value2"})
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

[image]

Comment: I am having issue with this method. I will test it and let you know.

Comment: @user206168 if you can't figure it out, please let me have an example that demonstrates the problem you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, maybe something like this :

```
Sub test()
Dim rgDt As Range: Dim arr: Dim el
Dim cell As Range: Dim c As Range: Dim d As Range
Dim x As Double: Dim y As Double
Dim rg As Range: Dim rgU As Range
Dim rgDtVal: Dim rgDel As Range

With ActiveSheet
Set rgDt = .Range("A2", .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
End With

Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each cell In rgDt.Columns(1).Cells: arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1: Next

For Each el In arr
    With rgDt.Columns(1)
        .Replace el, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 2)
        .Replace True, el, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With
    
    x = Application.Min(rg): y = Application.Min(rg.Offset(0, 1))
    Set c = rg.Find(x, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=rg(rg.Rows.Count, 1))
    Set d = rg.Offset(0, 1).Find(y, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=rg.Offset(0, 1)(rg.Rows.Count, 1))
    
    If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = y Then
        If rgU Is Nothing Then Set rgU = c Else Set rgU = Union(rgU, c)
    ElseIf d.Offset(0, -1).Value = x Then
        If rgU Is Nothing Then Set rgU = d Else Set rgU = Union(rgU, d)
    Else
        If rgU Is Nothing Then Set rgU = Union(c, d) Else Set rgU = Union(rgU, c, d)
    End If
Next

With rgDt
    rgDtVal = .Value
    .Value = "x"
    rgU.EntireRow.Value = ""
    Set rgDel = .SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    .Value = rgDtVal
End With

'rgU.EntireRow.Select
rgDel.Select
'rgDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

The rgDt variable is the range of Data, change to meet your case.
Then it create arr variable which contains the unique value in column 1 of rgDt.

Then it loop to each element in arr to get the range of cells offset 0,2 where column 1 has value of the looped element as rg variable.

variable x is the lowest value in rg
variable y is the lowest value in rg.offset(0,1)

then it set c variable to get the cell which value is x 
and set d variable to get the cell which value is y.

Now c is the cell with the lowest value1 of the looped el, 
and d is the cell with the lowest value2 of the looped el.

Sorry, I can't explain it further more because the English is too difficult for me.
 Anyway, in short, rgU variable is the union of cells of each looped el with the lowest value1 and value2.

Finally it create rgDel variable which is the inverse range of rgU in rgDt, then delete the entire row of rgDel.

Please remember to make a copy first if you want to test it, and STEP RUN it to know what is going on. You can add a temporary line such as  `c.select:d.select` after the variable is set. OR add `rgU.select` before the next iteration, etc.

[image] ---> [image]

It will take the first lowest-value found in the column.
For example on ID 500 in the image above, there are three lowest value in VAL1 column, then it keep the first found one which is in row 19. There are are three lowest value in VAL2 column, then it keep the first found one which is in row 18.

BUT, if the first found cell with lowest value to the left or to the right has the lowest value for it's neighour column, then it will take that row. Again, I'm sorry I can't explain it in a proper way since the English is too difficult for me. Anyway the example of this paragraph is in ID 600.